# How do I install sqlite on Laravel 5 for WAMP?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, wamp

I'm using Laravel 5 on my WAMP Server and I am trying to get sqlite to work on it so I can follow the tutorials properly. I've uncommented the following in php.ini and restarted the WAMP server.

- extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
- extension=php_sqlite.dll
- extension=php_sqlite3.dll

After restarting the server,
I've created a script to test if sqlite3 is supported or not located in C:\wamp2\www\laravel\test\test.php, and when I run it, the message says 'SQLite 3 supported.' So I know that it is working as far as that is concerned.

```
<?php
$dbname='base';
if(!class_exists('SQLite3'))
  die("SQLite 3 NOT supported.");

$base=new SQLite3($dbname, 0666);
echo "SQLite 3 supported."; 
?>
```

However, when I go into my database.php at: C:\wamp2\www\laravel\test\config\database.php and change the default to,

```
'default' => 'sqlite',
```

and then go into the cmd prompt to run the same command they do in the tutorial, which was: "C:\wamp2\www\laravel\test>sqlite3"

I get the error message

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In git it says:

> Joe@JOEALAI /C/wamp2/www/laravel/test
>   $ sqlite3
>   sh: sqlite3: command not found

When my default was at 'mysql', it ran perfectly and I was able to connect and create tables no problem.

I am completely stuck. Is there anyone that has had this experience and can help me through this?

Comment: Just because you have the php extension installed, doesn't mean you have actually SQLite installed.

Comment: I have the same problem @CharlotteDunois I installed the SQLite binaries as well but still when I type in command line it gives error! any help ?

Comment: I ended up just ditching WAMP and went through the homestead installation. It ended up being the better option, anyway. Much easier to use and configure than WAMP for Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

The `test.php` is just testing if the PHP module is installed.

I never worked with WAMP before but I'm pretty sure you need the actual sqlite3 programm installed on your server for the PHP module to work. Try downloading and installing the
*Precompiled Binaries for Windows* from their [website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).